# Sending PHP headers returns "502 Bad Gateway - The server returned an invalid or incomplete response."

Tags: php, http-headers

My php is getting kinda rough. So I apologize in advance if I'm asking something simple.

I'm migrating my site to a new hosting company and the following script that should start a binary (`.zip`) file download in a client's web browser:

```
$handle = fopen($name, 'r');
if($handle !== false)
{
    $length = filesize($name);

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache;\n");
    header("Pragma: no-cache;\n");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT;\n");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT;\n");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary;\n");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes;\n");
    header("Content-Length: $length;\n");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name_and_ext_only."\";\n\n");

    fpassthru($handle);

    fclose($handle);
    exit();
}
```

gives me the following error (tested in Google Chrome):

> **502 Bad Gateway**
>
> The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

I checked, the `$name` variable refers to an existing `.zip` file on the server of a non-zero length. From what I can tell, the issue happens when I try to output the headers.

The weird thing is that it used to work in the old hosting company.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try running a simple script that only echoes something? 502 Bad Gateway often means the web-server couldn't pass the file to the PHP CGI.

Comment: @Svenskunganka: I tried placing `echo("Here");exit();` line in that script and it works until the point when I start passing headers.

Comment: I'm not hype with headers, but try commenting them out each one by one and see which one breaks your code. It can also be that your host doesn't allow certain headers to be outputted or their web-server is misconfigured.

Comment: @Svenskunganka: There are 9 headers in my script. Following your suggestion, I will need to do it at least 512 times to be sure. I was trying to find a more logical way of fixing this.

Comment: No, you'd have to do it 9 times. Since it worked on your previous host, we can't really help you here. You should turn towards their support and ask why your headers invokes a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: @Svenskunganka: Yeah. Thanks. It defies me as well. I'll try to contact hosting site support now.